# How do I use a toggle switch to change text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, I have a pricing table and I'm trying to change the price when yearly is selected.

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<span class="price"></span>
```

I'm trying to make it so when the switch is toggled, it'll display the monthly price and when it's untoggled it'll display the yearly price. How do I do this in jQuery? I'm incredibly new to jQuery, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: You'll want to add an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) to the checkbox. From that list, [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is probably the right event to use. You can refer to the jQuery documentation for how to add an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var monthly="£12.00";
var yearly="£130.00";
$("label.switch input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $(".price").text(this.checked?yearly:monthly);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>Yearly
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label><br>

<span class="price">£130.00</span>
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
var month = [1, 2, 3];
var year = [100, 200, 300];
var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
var tempPrice;

//Run price change funtion tu set up prices
priceChange();
//Listener to switch change
$('.switch input').change(priceChange);


function priceChange() {
  //Loop for pirces
  for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    //Validator if checked for year values
    if (this.checked) {
      tempPrice = year[i];
    } else { //Else month values
      tempPrice = month[i];
    }
    prices[i].innerHTML = tempPrice;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="desktop">
  <tr>
    <th id="no-outline"><label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round">
                    </span>
</label>
    </th>
    <th class="plan-title">Micro
      <p id="price">$<span class="price"></span> per month</p><a class="button" href="/signup">Request a demo</a></th>
    <th class="plan-title">Venture
      <p id="price">$<span class="price"></span> per month</p><a class="button" href="/signup">Request a demo</a></th>
    <th class="plan-title">Established
      <p id="price">$<span class="price"></span> per month</p><a class="button" href="/signup">Request a demo</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="feature-section" id="first">Online presense &amp; branding</td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section" id="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Dedicated advisor</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Custom website design</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="first">Mobile-ready website</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Custom domain</td>
    <td>Varies</td>
    <td>Varies</td>
    <td>Free</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Logo branding</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Managed social media</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="feature-section" id="first">Ecommerce</td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section" id="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ecommerce support</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product listings</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Unlimited</td>
    <td>Unlimited</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SSL certificate included</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quickbooks compatible</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="feature-section" id="first">Security</td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section" id="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daily backups</td>
    <td>Yes, saved for 7 days</td>
    <td>Yes, saved for 30 days</td>
    <td>Yes, saved for 90 days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data encryption</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fraud detection</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two-factor authentication</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Advisor background check</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="feature-section" id="first">Data</td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section"></td>
    <td class="feature-section" id="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Disk space</td>
    <td>5GB</td>
    <td>25GB</td>
    <td>100GB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Manage customer help tickets</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chat with potential clients</td>
    <td>Up to 15 people per month</td>
    <td>Up to 150 people per month</td>
    <td>Up to 2,500 people per month</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Real-time user tracking</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Website analytics</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yours worked the best. How would I do the same with multiple elements? There's 3 different sections, how do I make it so 3 prices change? https://neutronwireless.com/plans

Comment: @OwenBick this would be my quickest solution. But you could improve it using arrays

Comment: @OwenBick hope this helps.

Comment: you're a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: @OwenBick you are welcome. Pliss dont forget upvoting and selecting my answer if it solved your problem. Have a good one

Comment: @OwenBick Hi owen, can i kindly remind you to upvote and accept my answer. Thank you